# Cypress test not failing from exception in mocked object

Tags: cypress

My test contains something like this:

```js
it.only('does something', function() {
    cy.window().then(function(win) {
      win.GlobalObject = {
        someMethod: function(data) {
          return expect(data).to.deep.eq({
            company: 'Pied Piperz',
            country: 'United States'
          });
        }
      };
    });
    cy.get('[data-cy=submit]').click();
});
```

When my test runs, part of the logic invokes `window.GlobalObject.someMethod({})` which should fail the test since I didn't pass the expected object into `someMethod()`.  Instead, I see a failing assertion in the log:

[image]

But the overall test is marked as succeeding:

[image]

How can I get get the failing asserting inside my mocked `GlobalObject` to fail the whole test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your test is failing AFTER it has already passed.

Once Cypress finishes `cy.get('[data-cy=submit]').click()`, it's done executing all the commands, so it considers your test to have completed.

Then, some milliseconds later, you have a failing `expect()` - but Cypress has already passed the test, so there is nothing meaningful to be done.

But all is not lost! You can use the optional `done` parameter to manually tell Cypress when the test has finished, like so:

```js
it.only('does something', function(done) { // <--- note `done` here
    cy.window().then(function(win) {
      win.GlobalObject = {
        someMethod: function(data) {
          expect(data).to.deep.eq({
            company: 'Pied Piperz',
            country: 'United States'
          });
          done(); // <--- this call tells Cypress the test is over
        }
      };
    });
    cy.get('[data-cy=submit]').click();
});
```